# frisby and read the response header with json response REST API

Tags: frisby.js

I am using frisby to automate the REST API testing. All of my REST API is based on json and return json response. In one of the requirement, I need to read the response header and fetch the response header and set it for next request. With json response, I am not able to read the response header. Following is sample code for my test.

```
frisby.create("Check to make sure that user does exist")
                                            .get(hostURL + "/api/users/checkusername/" + username, user, {json: true}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
                                            .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
                                            .afterJSON(function (response) {
                                            //How to read session id from header
                                                //var sessionId = res.headers[constants.SESSION_ID_HEADER_KEY]; 
                                                var exist = response.exist;
                                                expect(exist).toBe(true);

                                                });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You code was actually OK, you were just trying to use 'res' variable instead of response.

```js
frisby.create("Check to make sure that user does exist")
.get(hostURL + "/api/users/checkusername/" + username, user, {json: true}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
.expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
.afterJSON(function (response) {
  var sessionId = response.headers[constants.SESSION_ID_HEADER_KEY]; 
  // Use the sessionId in other frisby.create(...) call
}).
toss();
```

Another alternative is to use after() as follows:

```js
frisby.create("Check to make sure that user does exist")
.get(hostURL + "/api/users/checkusername/" + username, user, {json: true}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
.expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
.after(function (err, res, body) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(body);
  var sessionId = obj.headers[constants.SESSION_ID_HEADER_KEY]; 
  // Use the sessionId in other frisby.create(...) call
}).
toss();
```